# How to make a free payment

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay

> paymentContext.paymentAmount = 0

A may enter 0 when using coupons.

There was no problem with credit cards, but with ApplePay

crash log

```
Payment request is invalid: Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
```

Comment: What's is your purpose of making $0 payment transaction ?

Comment: it is because it becomes free when use a coupon.

Comment: I think you only need to move to payment success screen when user click on Pay instead of making an actual payment request. Apple Pay payment will later be sent over to payment gateway, then fee will incur. Even if possible to invoke Apple Pay for $0, i don't think it's wise choice